# Is there a rate-limit on the API of Trello?

Tags: trello

I started working with the Trello API and I asked myself if there is a limit on the API, similar to Twitter?

Let's say it otherwise, since there is no realtime API, my only way of updating data is polling the API, which may cause heavy load for the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [limit on the Trello API](http://help.trello.com/article/838-api-rate-limits), it is something like 300 requests per 10 seconds.

> To help prevent strain on Trello’s servers, our API imposes rate limits per API key for all issued tokens. There is a limit of 300 requests per 10 seconds for each API key. If a request exceeds the limit, Trello will return a 429 error.

In place of a realtime API you can use [WebHooks](https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/webhooks.html) which would let you avoid a lot of the issues.

Comment: This must be a recent post ! Thanks !

Comment: I get this error even if I wait longer than 10 s. It never clears. Is the limit really only per 10 s or is there another?